# Report compiler warnings in Jenkins using CMake

Tags: c++, jenkins, cmake

This should be simple however I'm struggling to find the correct setup for this.
I have a working declarative pipeline, compiling a c++ application using cmake on a Windows agent. I want to collect all the warnings and report on the dashboard.

According to the documentation the [Warnings Next Generation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/) easily support [cmake](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/SUPPORTED-FORMATS.md).

The relevant part of the pipeline looks this:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage( 'Build' ) {
            steps {
                cmake arguments: '''
                    -S .
                    -B build
                    -DQt6_DIR=C:\\Qt\\6.4.0\\msvc2019_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt6
                    ''', installation: 'InSearchPath'
                cmake arguments: '--build build --configuration Release', 
                  installation: 'InSearchPath'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: cmake()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the [CMake plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cmakebuilder/) configured as the documentation says, seen below:[image: Cmake global configuration]

I'm sure the configuration is correct because I can build the application with cmake. However I receive the following exception:

> There is no Cmake installation selected. Please review the build step configuration and make sure the installation is configured on the Global Tool Configuration page.

As the error says, I checked the global configuration. The 'path to cmake option is not set but on the build agents I use pre installed cmake and the path of it added to the `PATH` environment variable.

How can I tell this step where to find cmake?
If that not possible what are the alternative ways to report the compilation warnings?

I tried to redirect the output to a file and parse it, but the `cmake()` does not support the `pattern: "**/cmake_output.log"` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should consider myself lucky that I'm on windows. We use MSVC as a compiler so we can rely on the default generator for CMake - in this case some form of Visual Studio.

That means when we call the `cmake --build .` command under the hood MSBuild got called to manage the build. Therefore I can use the `msBuild()` parser of the Jenkins plugin to parse the output and generate the chart.
Jenkinsfile (snippet):

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        // not relevant, just use the default generator for cmake
    }
    post {
        always {
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: msBuild()
        }
    }
}
```